# What is the exact use of Strict mode Thread policy in android?

Tags: android, error-handling

Does `Strict mode Thread policy` class help to manage/handle errors?

If so what type of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> StrictMode is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them.

Warning: Don't use Strict Mode as a hack to do Network operations on Main thread since it will block your UI thread. This is a very very bad practice. Strict Mode is to help you catch any "accidental programming" by the developers

> StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread, where UI operations are received and animations take place. Keeping disk and network operations off the main thread makes for much smoother, more responsive applications. By keeping your application's main thread responsive, you also prevent ANR dialogs from being shown to users.

So you can use StrictMode to catch Disk/Network access without crashing your app. Be careful to turn it off when launching yout app on GP.

Comment: Yes, definitely. or IntentService. or Create a new Thread. But not on UI thread.